# Remove "Add-ins" from Excel Home tab

Tags: microsoft-excel

An "Add-ins" command appeared in the "Home" tab of my Excel ribbon today:
[image]

But it doesn't appear in the "Customize the Ribbon" dialog:
[image]

I'm running Office Home and Student 2019 on a Windows 10 machine. Any guidance on removing the "Add-ins" command from the ribbon would be appreciated.
Thanks.