# Get rid of Add-ins button on the Home tab of the Ribbon in Word 2021

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2021

Some time recently, something put an Add-ins section in my Home tab in the Ribbon. It only has one command, Add-ins, in it and I never plan to use it. It's not listed in Customize the Ribbon so I can't remove or move it there. The button can't even do anything as all I see is a little pop-up that starts with "The add-ins store has been disabled." I'm assuming some recent Word upgrade added it.
I'm using Word 2021.

**EDIT September 24, 2023**
A recent upgrade to Office has allowed me to remove this and I have no more complaints.

Comment: Higher quality relevant question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1805230/remove-add-ins-from-excel-home-tab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### As far as I know, this is new with release 2308. (fixed by 2401) You can't get rid of it. You can, though, create your own custom Home tab and substitute that

[image: screenshot]

See these two questions in the Microsoft Answers forum.

- [How to remove Add-ins from Home Ribbon in Word?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-remove-add-ins-from-home-ribbon-in-word/89aeade0-e0da-4e64-b518-29fe3b0c4f07)
- [Removing Add-ins From Home Tab of the Ribbon](https://Removing%20Add-ins%20From%20Home%20Ribbon)

You can and should [send feedback to Microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/giving-feedback-on-microsoft-word-or-other/8df81a9b-84aa-46ef-bf88-24fb7fec96ba?tm=1682959639719) about this. I consider it a bug.

Here are links to my feedback. Feel free to comment and vote.

1. [Word feedback](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/74024072-b14a-ee11-a81c-6045bdbbbc93)
2. [Excel feedback](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/bdb92b16-b34a-ee11-a81c-6045bdbbbc93)

### There is a workaround, though.

It is mentioned in the linked threads. You can create a custom Home tab and substitute it for the one that is built in. *I do not feel this is satisfactory and expect that, if enough people send negative feedback, MS will fix this.*

Update: They seem to have fixed this in that it can be removed using the Customize the Ribbon process. There is still access to Add-Ins but it is not in-your-face.

Comment: Thanks. Every time MS does something like this thinking they know what's best from me, I remember back to Word 2003 where I could customize literally every single Menu, Button bar, button ,icon, and right-click menu.

Comment: I also miss that ability. See my amended answer for a workaround. Also, you may want to look at https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/customize_ribbon_main.html.

Comment: That's a great idea. I"m not quite that annoyed yet but I'll keep it in mind. My regular Home tab is already customized to the max. Ironically, a few weeks ago I monkeyed with macros so Word automatically opens documents in Full screen so I don't even see the Ribbon most of the time.

Comment: The "Word feedback" and "Excel feedback" links in this post both have the same URL, which appears to be for the Word feedback. I think your Excel feedback URL was meant to be https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/bdb92b16-b34a-ee11-a81c-6045bdbbbc93

Comment: I changed the link for the Excel feedback. AFAIK, this has been fixed in that you can remove it using the Customize the Ribbon features.